# Select for many to many relation

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, laravel, many-to-many

I would like to understand how should a select according to my scheme look like. Since it's many to many relation, I have used binding table in the scheme.
[image: many to many scheme]

Now, my app situation is: I want to show all repairs for a vehicle with some `id`. In my function, I have that `id` stored in a variable let's say `$id` so I know what vehicle I want to see all repairs so the table `vehicles` is not important in this case for this select that I need.

So I want to write a select for specific vehicle where `repairs.vehicle_id = $id`.

One repair row has to contain columns worker `name` and `surname`. Later on, I have a table for parts ready to add into repairs but it will be same scenario like with workers so I just want to understand now, how can I write such `select` using `joins` and `group by` and other necessary sql functions to get workers working on the repair.

Of course, in one repair, there can be more workers.
Table `repair_worker` would look like this:

```
"repair_id" , "worker_id"
    "86"    ,     "2"
    "87"    ,     "3"
    "87"    ,     "4"
    "88"    ,     "1"
    "88"    ,     "2"
```

I am using Laravel framework but I would like to use only RAW SQL, no laravel functions if possible.

**EDIT:**

```
$repairs = DB::select(DB::raw('
            select r.id repair_id, w.name, w.surname
                from repairs r
                    join repair_worker rw on r.id = rw.repair_id
                    join workers w on w.id = rw.worker_id
                where r.vehicle_id = ?
                group by w.name, w.surname, r.id
'),[$vehicle->id]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the names of the workers, this should work:

```
select r.id repair_id, w.Name, w.SurName
from repairs r
join repair_worker rw on r.id = rw.repair_id
join workers w on w.id = rw.worker_id
where r.vehicle_id = $id
group by r.id, w.Name, w.SurName
```

To put the repair on a single row, with all the workers in a single column, you can do this:

```
select r.id repair_id, string_agg(w.Name || ' ' || w.SurName, ', ') workers
from repairs r
join repair_worker rw on r.id = rw.repair_id
join workers w on w.id = rw.worker_id
where r.vehicle_id = ?
group by r.id;
```

Comment: Can I use `$id` in sql raw?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Laravel, but I think you would pass in the argument like this: `$workers = DB::select('...where r.vehicle_id = ?', [1]);`  I assumed you already had that part taken care of.

Comment: I am going to try it. And how would your select change, if I also want to select repair id? Or even better (not sure if possible), select repair id and get all workers for that repair id in one "array" to print them out as one column?

Comment: I've added repair_id to the query.  Do you mean you want all the workers for a repair to be displayed in a single comma-separated field?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, exactly like that.

Comment: Btw, after you added `r.id`, I get this error: `Grouping error: 7 ERROR: column "r.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function` . Why does it want `r.id` in `group by` ?

Comment: I forgot to add `r.id` to the `group by`.  You need to include all fields that aren't being aggregated to the `group by`.

Comment: Okay. Im still trying to pass the `$id` but not lucky yet. What you posted in comment above with `[1]` doesnt work, I assume by `1` you mean `$id` ? But either way doesn't work.

Comment: Yes.  Can you post that section of your Laravel code?

Comment: Updated my question. And also, with that `string_agg` function I am getting syntax error in my IDE, where the part `' || w.surname, '` is red-underlined.

Comment: What version of postgresql are you using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142930/discussion-between-jerrad-and-ady96).

Comment: I have updated my question with working `where`. But the `string_agg` still no luck.